# Running javascript on a pop up window

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am working in PHP and I have an `add item` button on a page that when the user clicks will pop up a window using the `tinybox.js` script. The pop up window is a PHP page itself that retrieves some data from a db. On this pop up page I have some JavaScript with a + and - button so that the user can change a quantity. This works perfectly when loading the page directly but it seems that the JavaScript will not run when the page is a pop up.

Can anyone please tell me what I need to do to get the code to work on the pop up.

Here is the javascript for the change quantity buttons:

```
$(".ddd").on("click", function () {

    var $button = $(this),
        $input = $button.closest('.set-quantity').find("input.quantity-input");
    var oldValue = $input.val(),
        newVal;

    if ($.trim($button.text()) == "+") {
        newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
    } else {
        // Don't allow decrementing below zero
        if (oldValue > 1) {
            newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
        } else {
            newVal = 1;
        }
    }

    $input.val(newVal);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$(document).on("click", ".ddd", function () {
```

This will ensure your event is fired for elements not in the DOM when the event binding occurs. Hard to answer without more info regarding the state of the DOM at the point of this JS running (Some  would help you here regarding this "pop-up")

Taken from here: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21522499/attaching-event-to-future-elements-using-jquery)

Comment: Thanks a lot Dan, this did it ! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `body` before `.ddd` in your jquery.
Updated code is

```
$("body .ddd").on("click", function () {

    var $button = $(this),
        $input = $button.closest('.set-quantity').find("input.quantity-input");
    var oldValue = $input.val(),
        newVal;

    if ($.trim($button.text()) == "+") {
        newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) + 1;
    } else {
        // Don't allow decrementing below zero
        if (oldValue > 1) {
            newVal = parseFloat(oldValue) - 1;
        } else {
            newVal = 1;
        }
    }

    $input.val(newVal);

});
```